# Using Python APIs to download data and make pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I want to download data from [this website](https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/table/TS/M250141) using APIs that are made available.

However, the [code I have](https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/view-api/for-developers) with me only returns metadata.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url_path = "https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/tabledata/M250141?seriesNoORrowNo=13.1&between=0%2C4&sortby=value%20asc&offset=1&limit=5&timefilter=2013%201Q&search=land"
response = requests.get(url_path)
if response.ok:
    data = response.json()
    df_SG_DATA = pd.DataFrame(data['Data'])
    print(df_SG_DATA)
else:
    print(response)
```

Comment: you sure it should return anything else?

Comment: If you visit the webpage, there is a drop down menu called 'more'. It has API to download csv and json files. Instead of manual clicking and importing into pandas, I tried to automate using APIs

Comment: Please improve your question! What do you mean with meta data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL they give you as an example is riddled with filters:

- `seriesNoORrowNo=13.1` means the API will only return data for the record with the identifier `seriesNo:"13.1"`;
- `between=0%2C4` means the API will only return values between 0 and 4;
- `sortby=value%20asc` not a filter, it sorts the colomns by ascending values, I noticed it requires `seriesNoORrowNo` to be defined, else no value is returned;
- `offset=1` means the API won't send you its first record;
- `limit=5` means the API will only send you 5 records;
- `timefilter=2013%201Q` means the API will only send you values for the first quarter of 2013;
- `search=land` means the API will only send you values for records containing the word land.

You only receive metadata because no value match all these conditions.

Try to remove or relax some filters, you can use this url as an example: https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/tabledata/M250141?limit=50&timefilter=2013%201Q%2C2013%202Q&between=0%2C100&seriesNoORrowNo=1,1.1,1.1.1&sortby=value%20asc&offset=0

---

EDIT 20230409:

I edited your code a bit to help you handle the nested json answer from the API:

```py
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

# This sample url will return 5 records from the databank
# They will only contain values for the first and second
# quarters of 2013
url_path = "https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/tabledata/M250141?limit=5&timefilter=2013%201Q%2C2013%202Q&offset=0"
response = requests.get(url_path)

if response.ok:
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    
    # tell pandas to make a dataframe using the content of
    # "columns" ("key" and "value") but to also keep
    # "seriesNo" and "rowText"
    dataCurated = pd.json_normalize(
        data=data['Data'],
        record_path=['row','columns'],
        meta=[['row','seriesNo'],['row','rowText']],
        )

    # reorder the columns to make the table prettier
    df_SG_DATA = dataCurated.loc[:, ['row.seriesNo','row.rowText','key','value']]

    print(df_SG_DATA)
    #df_SG_DATA.to_csv("df_SG_DATA.csv")
else:
    print(response)
```

Here's the result you should get:

```
  row.seriesNo                                        row.rowText      key value
0            1  General Business Expectations (Forecast For Ne...  2013 1Q    12
1            1  General Business Expectations (Forecast For Ne...  2013 2Q     8
2          1.1                                        Electronics  2013 1Q    18
3          1.1                                        Electronics  2013 2Q     8
4        1.1.1                                     Semiconductors  2013 1Q    29
```

Comment: The output got is no different from what was got previously. Are you able to see any change in Output?

Comment: Vincent, are you from SG? Have you used this API before?

Comment: @prashanthmanohar With the url I gave you, you should see 2 columns of values, "2013 1Q" and "2013 2Q", and the first 3 records (seriesNO "1", "1.1", and "1.1.1"). It's only 6 values so maybe it's difficult to see the difference, try the following url that removes all filters and should allow you to download the complete table for the first 2000 records (2000 is the maximum the API let you request at once but if the table is larger, you can add a second request with offset=2000 to get records 2001 to 4000, etc...): https://tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/api/table/tabledata/M250141?

Comment: @prashanthmanohar No, I don't work there and I don't have any experience with this specific API but I've been getting data from online databases for some time so I'm starting to get used to their sometimes wacky documentation. If you still can't see any data with the new url I gave in the comment above, I'll put some code in the answer.

Comment: I have not got these 2 columns. But the URL is returning a lot of data in json format on my browser. The thing is I dont have much experience in handling json data also.

Comment: @prashanthmanohar I edited my answer to add some code to handle the nested json answer from the API. Finally, I decided to keep the fiscal quarters indication in a single column to make the table tidier and easier to work with.

Comment: The limit seems to be set to a maximum of 2000. Even when I set the limit to a much greater number, it does not return more.

Comment: @prashanthmanohar Yes, it's capped at 2000 so if you want more you'll have to make multiple requests and use the `offset` parameter. You make your first request with `offset=0`, then a second request with `offset=2000`, then a third with `offset=4000`, and you keep going for as long as you need (it shouldn't be hard to use a loop).